# VPN server access VPN client on its own initiative

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I have a Linux server with static IP address,  and a ARM linux behind some NAT and no direct access from Internet.

The ARM linux runs a small HTTP server listening on TCP port 80

Is it possible to have ARM linux to establish a VPN connection to the server,  and then the server is able to connect to ARM linux's 80 port on its own initiative over the VPN?

Comment: Certainly, why not? Just go do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% clear on your setup but I'm guessing its something like this:

Linux Server [static IP] < Network - maybe internet > Network Device [NATing] < Network > ARM Server

You can use something like StrongSwan to form a site to site VPN between the Linux Server and the ARM Server, so long as the two servers can connect to each other. StrongSwan supports NAT-D so the fact ARM device sits behind a device performing NAT won't be an issue.

Once the VPN is up and running both servers will have a tunnel running between through which the Linux Server can make HTTP requests to the ARM server.